# Set focus to child window in PyGtk

Tags: glade, pygobject

I am writing a simple application in python using PyGObject and glade. The application has a main window and a functional window (Generate logs, also a Window object) which opens up on clicking a menu item.

The Generate logs window is supposed to:

1. Show options to generate log for a particular date
2. Be minimizable and should close automatically when the task is complete (OR)
3. Be able to be closed manually if the user wishes so

The problem is, once I show up the Generate logs window, I am directly able to select the main window as well. Then, I can go to the menu and bring up as many Generate logs windows as I want.

I have tried several options (Is Focus, setting up main window as Transient parent etc) but nothing worked. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you say PyGTK, then you say PyGObject, this are 2 different things. I'm going to answer for PyGTK (my sources are from GTK+ 2 docs) since it's in the title and maybe people looking for that will end up here. But never fear, because for this question, the answer is practically (I think exactly) the same for both.

What I understand is that you want you "Generate log" window to be *modal*. That means other windows can't be used while your modal window is up, just like a Dialog window. Also you should set the main window to be the `parent` of your modal window, since this helps the OS Window Manager i.e. keep the dialog on top of the main window.

Yo can do both of this things directly from Glade (if you've created both windows in the same project, not always the case) selecting the *Modal* atribute to `True` and the *Transient for Window* attribute to your main window, in the General Properties section of your Generate log window.

Also you can do it programmatically using the `set_modal()` and the `set_transient_for(parent_window)` method of your child window.
Let's say your parent window is called `main_window` and the child window is `generate_log_window`, then you can do it like this:

```
generate_log_window.set_modal(gtk.TRUE)  
generate_log_window.set_transient_for(main_window)
```

If you want it to show center top of your main window, do this

```
generate_log_window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER_ON_PARENT)
```

To your second point, the ability to minimize can be set from Glade.

Sources:
[GTK+ 2 GtkWindow reference set_modal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-modal)
[GTK+ 2 GtkWindow reference set_transient_for](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-transient-for)
[PyGTK FAQ: How do I get my windows to show up where I want](http://eccentric.slavery.cx/misc/pygtk/pygtkfaq.html#10.3)
[PyGTK FAQ: How do I make a dialog block the whole application, so the user is forced to answer it?](http://eccentric.slavery.cx/misc/pygtk/pygtkfaq.html#10.4)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

create several windows (see your other post).
Upload them in **init**
Show them with "signals" in glade using "show" and "hide"

```
class GUIxxxx
  #...
  def action1(self, widget, data=None):
     self.window1.show()

  def action2(self, widget, data=None):
     # do something here
     self.window1.hide()
```

Comment: Doing this, I can hide the show only one of the windows at a time preventing access to the other one. While this mitigates the problem, I cannot hide the main window as that will be bad design. I was hoping to find an attribute which I can set for the Generate logs window so that it holds focus till it is closed